# mqjbnd64 not found in capitalware visual edit install

Tags: ibm-mq, mq-visual-edit

I've just installed the demo version of this but fail to connect to the default  queue manager. The error in the logs shows me that configuration is not correct for the mq dlls

2022/09/29 17:12:49 MQCmdServer: isCmdServerRunning: Error: MQJE001: Completion Code '2', Reason '2495'.

2022/09/29 17:12:49 MQCmdServer: isCmdServerRunning: getCause()=com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2495;AMQ8568: The native JNI library 'mqjbnd64' was not found. For a client installation this is expected. [3=mqjbnd64]

I've tried everything I can to set the path and java.library.path correctly but it all fails. They appear in the visual edit logs as being set but it makes no difference to the outcome.

Visual edit log also tells me that it should have the mq jars in its install directory:

C:\Capitalware\MQVE3\com.ibm.mq.commonservices.jar;

but these are not there and are nowhere to be seen. So, I'm mystified as to what version of the client it's using and therefore what help I can give it. I'm wondering if it's using a different version of the client from the one I have installed and so the dll and mq java lib have a mismatch? Or, if it's using the client I have installed then how is it finding it - because it's not in the paths that I've got in the visual edit logs !

Any thoughts anyone? What can I do to investigate further?

thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Background: There are 2 ways an MQ client application can connect to a queue manager:

(1) Bindings mode means that the MQ client application is connecting to a local (i.e. on the same server) queue manager

(2) Client mode means that the MQ client application will connect to a remote queue manager by specifying the hostname/IP address, port # and channel name

> CC=2;RC=2495;AMQ8568: The native JNI library 'mqjbnd64' was not found. For a client installation this is expected. [3=mqjbnd64]

This error mean that you are trying to connect to a local queue manager (in bindings mode) but there is no local queue manager.  MQ client library uses the 'mqjbnd64' DLL to handle the connection to the local queue manager.  But clearly, the queue manager is remote to where MQ Visual Edit is running.

Go back to the Queue Manager Access Profile, click on the Remote icon, then fill in the channel name, hostname/IP address and port # of the remote queue manager, save the information then you should be able to the remote queue manager.

[image]